# String to Date Formatting in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, tableau-api

I have a list of strings such as 6/20/2019 that I need to convert to date format in BigQuery. Have issues with the leading 0's and this text being recognized as an actual date/time format when being used in BigQuery SQL or being pulled into Tableau as such.

Comment: also the months are listed as single digits, such as 5/4/2019, looking for a solution for both day and month parts

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't `parse_date()` work?

```
select parse_date('%m/%d/%Y', '6/20/2019')
```

Comment: That doesn't work with single digit months. `%m` expects it to be with a leading 0. So in the example here it requires `06`. For some reason they did decide to support it for day (`%d` for `03` and `%e` for `3`), but not for single digit months. See: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements#format_elements_date_time

Comment: Never mind, %d and %m do handle single digit days and months, even though it is not documented like that. My error was due a different reason.